# Unable to invoke JavaScript function with RegisterStartupScript while downloading a file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

Please help me decipher this issue. No matter what I try, in any variation, the RegisterStartupScript does NOT invoke the JavaScript on the appx

Here is the code in aspx

```
    <asp:GridView id="gvOutboundResults" runat="server" 
        Visible="true"
        GridLines="Horizontal" 
        BorderWidth="0" 
        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" 
        EnableViewState="true" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        OnRowCommand="btnDownloadFile_Click" 
        CssClass="col-md-12">
        <EmptyDataRowStyle BorderWidth="0" BorderStyle="None"
            HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderColor="White" />
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            No Downloads Available
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" CssClass="Erow"/>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#69E2EF" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="white"/>
        <PagerStyle ForeColor="#2461BF" BackColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <HeaderStyle ForeColor="Black" BackColor="White" Font-Size="Medium" Font-Names="Arial" BorderWidth="0" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#f1f1f1" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <Columns>        
            <asp:TemplateField 
                HeaderStyle-Width="300px"
                HeaderText="Download File" 
                HeaderStyle-Font-Size="13px">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="imgDownload" runat="server"  
                        ImageUrl="~/images/download.ico" 
                        ToolTip="Download File"
                        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("File_Name") %>'
                        CausesValidation="false" 
                        CommandName="Download"
                        OnClientClick="StartDownload(this)" />
                    <div id="imgDownloading" runat="server" style="display:none">
                        <span class="ld ld-ring ld-spin"></span>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Here is my code behind for the btnDownloadFile_Click event where I tried every version of RegisterStartupScript call, with script tags, without, with semicolons, without, etc

```
protected void btnDownloadFile_Click(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

    try
    {

        lblMessage.Text = string.Empty;
        lblMessage.Visible = false;

        if (e.CommandName == "Download")
        {
            string fileName = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            string filePath = myLocation;
            drms_utilities.DownloadFile(this, filePath, lblMessage);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = exception.Message;
        lblMessage.Visible = true;
        drmsda.InsertErrorlog(pageName, "External: Error Occtured in btnDownloadFile_Click Event.", exception.Source, exception.Message + " " + exception.StackTrace, "");
    }
    finally
    {
        String csname1 = "PopupScript";
        Type cstype = this.GetType();
        // Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
        ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

        // Check to see if the startup script is already registered.
        if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname1))
        {
            string function = "FinishDownload('" + imageButton.ClientID + "')";
            cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, "alert('anton');", false);
        }

        ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);
        if (sm.IsInAsyncPostBack)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "anotherKey", "someAlert();", true);
        }
        else
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "anotherKey", "Sys.Application.add_load(someAlert);", true);
        }

        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "anotherKey", "Sys.Application.add_load(someAlert)", true);
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "anotherKey", "someAlert();", true);
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "anotherKey", "someAlert()", true);
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "anotherKey", "<script language='javascript'>someAlert()</script>", true);
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "anotherKey", "<script language='javascript'>someAlert();</script>", true);

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "anotherKey", "Sys.Application.add_load(someAlert)", true);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "anotherKey", "someAlert();", true);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "anotherKey", "someAlert()", true);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "anotherKey", "<script language='javascript'>someAlert()</script>", true);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "anotherKey", "<script language='javascript'>someAlert();</script>", true);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "anotherKey", "Sys.Application.add_load(someAlert)", true);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "anotherKey", "someAlert();", true);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "anotherKey", "someAlert()", true);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "anotherKey", "<script language='javascript'>someAlert()</script>", true);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "anotherKey", "<script language='javascript'>someAlert();</script>", true);

    }
}
```

Just in case here is my JavaScript function

```
function someAlert()
{
    alert('Hi I am registered');
}
```

Function call for DownloadFile contains the following code

```
            var ZipFile = new FileInfo(archivePath);
            archiveName = Path.GetFileName(archivePath);
            page.Response.Clear();
            page.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename=\"{0}\"", archiveName));
            page.Response.ContentType = "application/x-zip-compressed";
            page.Response.WriteFile(ZipFile.FullName);
            page.Response.End();
```

The code seems to work without this function call

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Your `DownloadFile` method clears the current response and streams a file back to the browser. None of the JS registration code in your `btnDownloadFile_Click` handler will have any effect at all.

You're trying to do something after a file has been downloaded, yes ?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to reset the UI (hide/show button) when the browser receives the file, not when the the download is complete